# Adding Date and Months in Formula using Process Builder

Tags: formula, process-builder

I am adding Opportunity Close Date with Format DD/MM/YYYY to Length of Contract in Months in Process Builder

Close Date field format is DD/MM/YYYY

Here is my formula:
MONTH([Opportunity].CloseDate)+ MONTH([Opportunity].Length_of_Contract_Months__c)

But it throws this error
The formula expression is invalid: Incorrect parameter type for function 'MONTH()'. Expected Date, received Number

Comment: This is very clearly explained in the Salesforce Help [formula reference](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5).  If you are new to Salesforce, you should definitely complete the Trailhead modules for [Formulas and Validations](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/point_click_business_logic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems Length_of_Contract_Months__c field is not a date field. It's number field. if Length of contact months is number and equivalent to months, then You don't need to convert them in months.

```
Here is my formula: MONTH([Opportunity].CloseDate))+ Opportunity.Length_of_Contract_Months__c
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you're getting error: You try to take month from a Number field. Month() function takes Date field and returns month from that date.

How to achieve what you're trying to do:

```
MONTH([Opportunity].CloseDate)) + Opportunity.Length_of_Contract_Months__c
```